# DOM live editor using Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js

I'm curious about the technology used by Optimizely, Abtasty, vwo... Those websites present you with a live visual DOM editor where you can move DOM elements around the page, change texts and more.

It's basically a FireBug like module but not attached to the browser.

Is there any javascript modules (jQuery plugins, NodeJs..) that can do that or even get close to it ?

Comment: I think they work with specific frameworks (such Drupal, Wordpress, etc...) for the live editing, isn't it?

Comment: It's purely Javascript I'm guessing, no dependencies on a cms I guess

Comment: That is definitely a JavaScript (probably using jQuery - definitely not Node.js). However this isn't on topic here.

Answer (score 0):

There are countless amount of technologies that are available for Web App Development, it's hard to say with what technologies that particular application was built in.

On the other hand, JavaScript is perfectly capable of building a WYSIWYG Editors, JQuery UI provides great templates to get started with.